# Google Volley Singleton pattern Request Queue Lints

Tags: android, android-volley, android-lint

I have been trying to implement `Volley` in my project. I am using google developers [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) for understanding the concepts.

In the second lesson, setting up `RequestQueue` as a singleton(Recommended practice) is taught. The following is a code snippet from that [lesson](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton).

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private MySingleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
```

Now coming to my question, when I followed this code I'm getting lints (in Android Studio 2.2) as follows.

> Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static
> reference to ApiRequestQueue which has field context pointing to
> Context); this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)

For the lines 2 and 5 in the above snippet.

What should I do? Should I suppress them or is there a way around?

Thanks.

Comment: Its just a warning, it means use the application context rather than the activity context.

Comment: @Enzokie, So if we pass application context instead of activity context will that lint go away?

Comment: @29 I am not 100% sure but I think yes since it is the Application context on a static variable.

Comment: @Enzokie, Thanks, will try that and get back to you.

Comment: @Enzokie Sorry, that didn't work for me.